# Spring STS 3.8.1 funciona muy lento en Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, spring-mvc

Esta semana mi spring en ubuntu anda demasiado lento, al punto que pierdo mucho tiempo haciendo clean a mi proyecto, esperar a que compile y es ahí donde se queda pegado. EL proyecto es un proyecto mvc con maven y gestionamos el versionado con git (con el cliente smartgit). Mi máquina tiene buenas prestaciones (core i7, 8 de ram con un disco de estado sólido). Recién que instalé todo en mi ubuntu corria de maravilla, pero desde esta semana es que se ha presentado este problema.
La verdad siempre he tenido algunos problemas con spring, inclusive en windows, he hecho lo que recomiendan, desactivar el build automático, las validaciones y otras tantas cosas pero sin resultados.

Comment: ¿Haz intentado con eclipse y los plugins de spring?

Comment: si Gemasoft, también lo he hecho con eclipse neon y el pluging y sigue igual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno chicos por fin logré solucionar el problema. Comparto la solución por si alguien llega a tener el mismo inconveniente.

En el lanzador de mi spring simplemente agregué los atributos

**-vmargs -Xmx2112M -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M**

El archivo del lanzador quedó de la siguiente manera:

> [Desktop Entry] Name=Spring Comment=Spring
>   Exec=/home/julian/Documentos/programas/sts-bundle/sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/STS
>   -vmargs -Xmx2112M -XX:PermSize=512M -XX:MaxPermSize=1024M Icon=/home/julian/Documentos/programas/sts-bundle/sts-3.8.1.RELEASE/icon.xpm
>   Terminal=false Type=Application

Answer (score 1):

Como nota adicional agregar el parametro `-Xverify:none` en el archivo de configuración `.ini`

Mejora bastante el arranque para versiones 3.X